# how to apply Zend_Filter_StripTags on array in zendFramework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

i want to apply `Zend_Filter_StripTags` on object array

```
$my_result = $obj->listdata(calling select query from model)
```

returned array is like

```
$my_result = 
 array  
      0 => 
         array
             'id' => string '1' (length=1)
             'value' => string '<script>' (length=10)
      1 => 
         array
             'id' => string '2' (length=1)
             'value' => string '<div>value</div>' (length=15)
```

how do i apply `Zend_Filter_StripTags` to `$my_result`

and i am passing this array to smarty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$my_result = $obj->listdata(calling select query from model);
$filter = new Zend_Filter_StripTags();
$result = array_map(array($filter, 'filter'), $my_result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$allowed_tags = array('img', 'a', 'strong', 'span');
$allowed_attributes = array('alt', 'href', 'width', 'height');

$filter = new Zend_Filter_StripTags($allowed_tags, $allowed_attributes);
$output = array_map(array($filter, 'filter'), $my_result);
```

Not tested because of no env.

Edit:

After you pasted a var dump try this:

```
$allowed_tags = array('img', 'a', 'strong', 'span');
$allowed_attributes = array('alt', 'href', 'width', 'height');

$filter = new Zend_Filter_StripTags($allowed_tags, $allowed_attributes);
$output = array();
foreach ( $my_result as $data ) {
    $data['value'] = $filter->filter($data['value']);
    $output[] = $data;
}
```

Comment: actually i don't want any tags

Comment: So what about simple `strip_tags` instead of this filter ?